# motor movement as in and output

Tags: stepper-motor, servo

I am looking for a way to counteract an active servo or stepper motor.

In more detail:
I want to translate the movement of a controllable motor to a linear rod movement.
This rod goes up and down continuously up to a certain threshold. 
The user should then be able to push the moving rod down to establish a new - lower - threshold. Also the user should be able to pull the moving rod in order to establish a new - higher - threshold.

I read you can use a servo both as input and as output but not on the same time. Is there any motor that can do this? So it should actually let go upward movements when a certain push force is applied to the rod.

I would really like to use as little components as possible since the final installation should be a multiplication of this a quite a small space.

Thanks in advance for thinking with me!

Comment: Can I for instance use brushless motors? I can't find anywhere whether I can somehow read out input movement of the motor.

Comment: What kind of force, speed and accuracy are you looking for? One example of what you're talking about is the motorized linear potentiometers used in automated sound-mixing boards.

Comment: Wow, yes that motorized linear potentiometers would certainly be something to look into. I am wondering though if they would still work when a (small) rod is attached to it because I read the human counteracting is sensed capacitive.

Answer (score 1):

The motorized linear potentiometers (like [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10976) on SparkFun) have two potentiometers and a motor. There is no capacitive element. One of the potentiometers is used for the volume control, the other for feedback on the linear position.

You would have to make a controller--maybe with an Arduino--to read the potentiometer to get the position and drive the motor to the desired position. When the motor is off a human can move the slider and the controller would detect that movement via the same potentiometer.

I think this would work well for your application with the assumption that you don't need a lot of force on your rod. If you need more force you'd need a larger linear actuator with feedback.